# Rails (3.2.7): override image_tag for asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, overriding, asset-pipeline, rails-api

**development.rb:**

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "assets.myserver.com"
```

**view script:**

```
<%= image_tag('header.jpg') %>
```

**yields:**

```
<img alt="Header" src="/header.jpg" />
```

**should be:**

```
<img alt="Header" src="http://assets.myserver.com/header.jpg" />
```

I am using the `rails-api` gem which I am guessing disables some asset and view rendering stuff.

It seems like it should not be too hard to re-implement (override `image_tag`) to add this very small feature. It may seem a little odd to want to do this. However, I am new-ish to rails would like to know how to do this as a learning experience.

Questions:

1. As a best practice where should I place this new code in the file structure?
2. What should I name the file with the new code?
3. How does rails know to look at the new code instead of looking at the old image_tag function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833488/rails-3-2-asset-host-setting-ignored

Answer (score 3):

I've tried your configuration, but when I use `config.action_controller.asset_host = "assets.myserver.com"` in my `development.rb` `image_tag` works as expected:

```
<img alt="Header" src="http://assets.myserver.com/assets/header.jpg" />
```

I've tested it both under Rails 3.2.7 and 3.2.8, but it works in both versions.

**UPDATE**

In my original answer I didn't use the `rails-api` gem. When using the `rails-api` gem `image_tag` works as described in the question.

Well to answer the actual question, you could add an initializer in `config/initializers`. Just create a file, lets say `image_tag_helper.rb`, with the following code:

```
# config/initializers/image_tag_helper.rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetTagHelper
      def image_tag(source, options = {})
        options[:src] = "http://#{source}"
        tag("img", options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What this basically does is reopening the module and replace the `image_tag` method with your own method. All other methods within the `module AssetTagHelper` remain the same. Take a look at the Rails [repository at github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e826a5c749f9a4029a3b2a7e3d371498feeb9b10/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L356) for a complete 'example' of the `image_tag` method.

The name of the file doesn't really matter. All files within `config/initializers` are loaded when the application is booted.

Basically this is a language feature of Ruby, Ruby allows you to reopen classes everywhere in your code and add or replace methods (you find more on this subject at [rubylearning.com](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overriding_methods.html)).

Comment: Are you using the `rails-api` gem?

Comment: no I don't, I apparently missed that line when reading your question.