# Rails 3.2 asset_host setting ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My production environment -

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.assets.enabled = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  #config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  config.log_level = :warn
  config.log_tags = [:remote_ip, lambda { |req| Time.now }]

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
    unless source.starts_with?('/stylesheets' || '/javascripts')
      "//dddd.cloudfront.net/"
    end
   }
```

However, when I using image_tag it still returns me '/assets..' relative url and not absolute url to the asset host.

```
irb(main):034:0> helper.image_tag('noimage.gif')
=> "<img alt=\"Noimage\" src=\"/assets/noimage.gif\" />"
irb(main):035:0> helper.image_path('noimage.gif')
```

I can not seem to figure what might be missing. I even tried doing simple config.asset_host setting, and still it does not recognize the setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the designated config?

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://abcd.cloudfront.net'
```

Not sure it works with protocol relative urls. I simply use https in my apps.

It might also be worth noting that action mailer has a similar setting:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://abcd.cloudfront.net'
```

Comment: Yes, I tried without protocol relative url as well. It did not work either.

Comment: There was issue with my config file, which prevented this from working. After stripped it out to the bare minimum - the asset_host seem to work with https:// prefix. So it is not working with protocol relative URL, with full URL it does work. thanks!

Comment: @Shekhar what was the problem that prevented that from working? i'm having the same problem. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

There's something odd in Rails configuration. According to the documentation `asset_host` is supposed to hold just the `host` part ('yoursite.com'). I resolved with an helper:

```
module EmailsHelper

  def email_image_tag(src) 
    protocol = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:protocol] || 'http'
    image_tag asset_path(src, protocol: protocol)
  end

end
```

Configure it in your mailer:

```
class EmailNotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  add_template_helper(EmailsHelper)
  ...

end
```

There's no way to force image_tag to use a URL other than to pass a URL to it.